# Where exactly is the "Before Header Content hook" in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a little code to the "Before Header Content hook" but I don't know where that is... Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

> Try:

```
add_action('init', 'process_post');
function process_post()
{
 echo "test";
}
```

Comment: I add it to the functions file? Thanks

Comment: i have added a modified version of your answer below .. please take a look

Answer (score 1):

**this is a modified version of @ajay 's solution**

if you are going to use this, then you have to make sure that the current user is not an admin using [is_admin() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/).. and only display it if he is not an admin ...

why !?

because if you didn't, it may mess up the wp-admin of your website..

```
add_action('init', 'process_post');
function process_post()
{
  if (!is_admin()) {
    echo "test";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be tricky simply because every theme differs with how the loop is displayed, however you could create a plugin to use the loop_start action, which is called before the first post of the standard WP loop:

```html
add_action( 'loop_start', 'test_loop_start' );

    function test_loop_start( $query ){
        echo 'this is my inserted text';
    }
```

Now using this would display it every single time the loop is called (whether on a page, a post, category page, search page, etc.), which you may not want.

```html
add_action( 'loop_start', 'test_loop_start' );

function test_loop_start( $query ){

    if(is_category() OR is_singular()) { 
    echo 'this is my inserted text';
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact, this will show the text before post content not before header..